# Check for decimal on masked textbox in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, maskedtextbox

I've got a masked textbox with the mask to be `_____.__`.

Now someone can just put in `00001.__`. And it still works, but I need people to enter a decimal number. Also, how can I put a check on this?

Comment: I suggest you show what you have already tried otherwise you are unlikely to get much interest see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

In an event like `TextChanged` you can use:

```
if (maskedTextBox1.MaskCompleted == true)
{
    // Invalid input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be better just to convert the textbox to a decimal or double, since the lack of decimal numbers just means ".00".

So, you may:

1. Set the mask of control to "000000.00" or even use as it is now.
2. Convert it to double or decimal:
       Dim DecNum as Double = CDbl(maskedTextBox.text)
       Dim DecNum as Decimal = CDec(maskedTextBox.text)

So, if the user had informed a decimal number, you would have it; otherwise your number will consider ".__" as ".00".

Comment: previous post worked, but I think this is even better! Thank you!

Comment: You´re welcome. Please vote if you feel I helped you :)   Good luck.